# ¿Cómo seleccionar el último registro introducido en la base de datos?

Tags: php

Quería saber si es posible realizar una consulta a la base de datos en función de unos parámetros, y que elimine el registro más cercano a la fecha actual, el último que se ha metido vaya. Este código me obtiene todos los resultados que quiero manipular, pero quiero separar el último registro del resto.

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM mensajes_privados WHERE id LIKE :id OR en_que_hilo LIKE :id ORDER BY fecha DESC");
$statement->execute(array(":id" => $codigo_mensaje));
$contenido_mensaje_privado = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Podría hacerlo con un `for` pero el código se haría más pesado. El motivo por el que quiero separar el último registro es porque lo quiero situar fuera del flujo del resto de registros, y si hago un bucle `foreach` me va a incluir también el último registro.

Comment: No es claro: _El motivo por el que quiero separar el último registro es porque lo quiero situar fuera del flujo del resto de registros_ ¿Qué quieres?  1º. Seleccionar **todos los registros excepto el último porque no lo necesitas para nada**, o 2º. Si quieres seleccionar **todos los registros incluido el último, pero excluirlo de un bucle en el que leerías los demás registros, reservando ese registro excluido para otro uso**. Lo digo porque si es lo 2º hay que buscar una forma de leer en bucle sacando ese registro (para no tener que hacer dos SELECT), si es lo 1º es pan comido.

Comment: Perdón, es exactamente el segundo caso que comentas. Sabría hacerlo de una u otra forma, pero por intentar acortar el máximo código posible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es muy simple.

1. Haces tu `SELECT ...` de forma normal, haciendo que el mismo te traiga los datos **ordenados adecuadamente.**
2. Usando PDO o MySQLi, puedes almacenar los resultados en un array asociativo.
3. En la variable que almacena los datos puedes usar **[`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-pop.php)**  para extraer del array de los datos el último valor y usarlo aparte.

Aquí tienes un código de ejemplo.

En el mismo, almacenas **todos los resultados** en la variable `$arrDatos` haciendo esto:

```
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Luego extraes de `$arrDatos` el último registro mediante:

```
$arrLast = array_pop($arrDatos);
```

Tendrás entonces dos arrays, en `$arrDatos` estarán todos los registros *menos* el último, el cual se encontrará en `$arrLast`. Luego puedes leer y usar cada uno como mejor te convenga. La **clave** es que el `SELECT ...` traiga los datos **ordenados** de la manera esperada.

**<kbd>[VER DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/29ut-7wdg)</kbd>**

```
<?php

/**
 * PDO MySQL 
 * 
*/

require "util/public_db_info.php";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);
echo "<pre>";

/**
 *  Verificar si hay datos  
 *  Y  sacar el  contenido  usando foreach
 *  Nótese el uso de  count($arrDatos)  para contar el total de registros
*/


$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE ean=:ean";    
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":ean",4);
$stmt ->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($arrDatos)
{
    echo "CONSULTA  1:  SE ENCONTRARON  ".count($arrDatos). " REGISTROS\n";
    echo "IMPRIMIENDO   TODOS LOS REGISTROS\n";

    print_r($arrDatos);    

    echo "IMPRIMIENDO EL ÚLTIMO REGISTRO SACADO APARTE\n";
    $arrLast = array_pop($arrDatos);
    print_r($arrLast);

    echo "IMPRIMIENDO EL ARRAY ORIGINAL PERO SIN EL ÚLTIMO REGISTRO\n";
    print_r($arrDatos);    


    $strLibros="LISTA DE LIBROS CONSULTA 1:\n";
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
    {
        $strLibros.= "id: ".$row["id"]." título: ".$row["title"]."\n";
    }
    echo $strLibros;

}
else
{
    echo "No hay datos";
}



echo "</pre>";


$pdo = null;


?>
```

**Resultado:**

```
CONSULTA  1:  SE ENCONTRARON  6 REGISTROS
IMPRIMIENDO   TODOS LOS REGISTROS
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38053
            [title] => Hamlet
            [isbn] => 3
            [ean] => 4
            [year] => dsf/
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38054
            [title] => Romeo y Julieta
            [isbn] => 5
            [ean] => 4
            [year] => dsf/
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38055
            [title] => Lo que el viento se llevó
            [isbn] => 3
            [ean] => 4
            [year] => dsf/
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38056
            [title] => No hay amor más grande
            [isbn] => 5
            [ean] => 4
            [year] => dsf/
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38057
            [title] => El Principito
            [isbn] => 3
            [ean] => 4
            [year] => dsf/
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38058
            [title] => El Quijote
            [isbn] => 5
            [ean] => 4
            [year] => dsf/
        )

)
IMPRIMIENDO EL ÚLTIMO REGISTRO SACADO APARTE
Array
(
    [id] => 38058
    [title] => El Quijote
    [isbn] => 5
    [ean] => 4
    [year] => dsf/
)
IMPRIMIENDO EL ARRAY ORIGINAL PERO SIN EL ÚLTIMO REGISTRO
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38053
            [title] => Hamlet
            [isbn] => 3
            [ean] => 4
            [year] => dsf/
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38054
            [title] => Romeo y Julieta
            [isbn] => 5
            [ean] => 4
            [year] => dsf/
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38055
            [title] => Lo que el viento se llevó
            [isbn] => 3
            [ean] => 4
            [year] => dsf/
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38056
            [title] => No hay amor más grande
            [isbn] => 5
            [ean] => 4
            [year] => dsf/
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38057
            [title] => El Principito
            [isbn] => 3
            [ean] => 4
            [year] => dsf/
        )

)
LISTA DE LIBROS CONSULTA 1:
id: 38053 título: Hamlet
id: 38054 título: Romeo y Julieta
id: 38055 título: Lo que el viento se llevó
id: 38056 título: No hay amor más grande
id: 38057 título: El Principito
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias como siempre! Gran respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que deseas es excluir ese registro, utiliza la sentencia mencionada en la respuesta de Francisco, y con las claves del mismo la excluyes en una nueva consulta.

```
SELECT* FROM mensajes_privados WHERE (id like :id OR en_que_hilo like :id) and id <> hilo_a_excluir
```

El único problema es que te verías forzado a hacer 2 consultas a la base. Espero te sirva, saludos.